# INSPIRE Directive Land Cover

Tags: land-cover, inspire

I have a doubt about INSPIRE directive. In case a Member States of EU does not have cartography of Land Cover, it is bound to produce it?

Comment: Assuming the member state (or more likely an organization within the state) has the data, there is a time table laid out for when the data has to be available.  The first obligation was to provide metadata, the next is/was to provide a view service, the final obligation is to provide some download service.  As it stands you should be able to work out through metadata available now, whether a data download or view service will be available.  See http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/discovery/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not best person to interpret the EU legislation but on the first pages of the INSPIRE directive http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2007:108:0001:0014:EN:PDF you can read:

> (13) This Directive should not set requirements for the collection of
>   new data, or for reporting such information to the Commission, since
>   those matters are regulated by other legislation related to the
>   environment.

Thus if member state does not have data for producing INSPIRE compliant services the INSPIRE directive does not mandate to acquire such data. However, other legislation may require that. When new data are collected it must be done so that INSPIRE services are supported (article 6).

> 3. Member States shall ensure that all newly collected and extensively restructured spatial data sets and the corresponding spatial data
>      services are available in conformity with the implementing rules
>      referred to in paragraph 1 within two years of their adoption, and
>      that other spatial data sets and services still in use are available
>      in conformity with the implementing rules within seven years of their
>      adoption. Spatial data sets shall be made available in conformity with
>      the implementing rules either through the adaptation of existing
>      spatial data sets or through the transformation services referred to
>      point (d) of Article 11(1).

If you mean by missing cartography that some member state has any data for producing a view service about Land Cover, then my interpretation is that member state is bound to produce such service.

> Article 11
>   1. Member States shall establish and operate a network of the following services for the spatial data sets and services for which
>   metadata have been created in accordance with this Directive: ... (b)
>   view services making it possible, as a minimum, to display, navigate,
>   zoom in/out, pan, or overlay viewable spatial data sets and to display
>   legend information and any relevant content of metadata; ...

Comment: In addition to this excellent answer I want to point to the INSPIRE thematic clusters, which are located at https://themes.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ and can provide specific answers for INSPIRE questions.